# How to do a copy of spreadsheet of google with their code (command sequence), without ask for permission for run de code?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I want to create a copy of a spreadsheet with her code, but when I do and I try to run the code that I had assigned a figure, like a button, google tells me that I need to give an authorization. What I want is to do a copy of the spreadsheet with her code, and when a run the code, that not ask me for authorization.
if someone knows something, I give thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You can't transfer authorization. The user needs to authorize the script in the new file manually.

Imagine if the code was malicious, for example, scraping the users data and sending it to someone. Whenever a user's data is involved, you need permission.

> https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/10130420?hl=en&ref_topic=7188760